# Close window jquery

Tags: jquery, window, refresh

Is it possible to do with jQuery to do something (like alert if I close window) ONLY if the window is closed, because if I refresh the page, or submit a form I always be credited as the page closed.

```
jQuery(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
       if($(".ontick").length==0){
       alert ('close?');}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JS "sees" only in context of the page, a reload an a page triggers the same event as closing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var refresh = false;  //Control variable to control refresh access

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
 if (refresh == false) { // If F5 is not pressed
   return 'You are about to close window!';
  }
}

$(window).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 116) { // User presses F5 to refresh
    refresh = true;
  }
});
```